# How to suppress the word VBScript in message box title?

Tags: vbscript

"Vbscript" always appears in my message box titles. How do I supress it
in VbScript code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are refering to using MsgBox from with in Internet Explorer, right?

You can't, its part of the means by which it IE protects the user from malicious sites trying to pretend to be something they are not.

Comment: But the main confusion is when I am using msgbox in my local code the VBSCRIPT is not appearing in the tilte. The browser is IE7. When the same code is deployed in our QA site the VBSCRIPT is appearing in the same IE7 browser. This is quite intriguing...
Any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: @Mini: I can't repeat this behaviour in IE8.  It might be zone thing although I've tried it in Internet, intranet and trusted zones all still include the "VBScript:" prefix.  Although it may be that you have different setting for one or more of these zones. I can't think of any setting that specifically relaxes this.

Answer (score -1):

@Mini: It was quite difficult to find out some solution but was surprised to see that it could be done with some simple steps.

Just Add you Site to Trusted Zone.